# Can't use EL 2.2 to pass item parameter to bean if list of items changes between refreshes?

Tags: java, jsf, el, tomcat7

I'm using EL 2.2's functionality (with Tomcat 7) to pass parameters (in this case, entire items) from a JSF page to a backing bean.
It's proving to be very handy, but I'm running into a gigantic problem when the list of items is changed by another user between page refreshes.
Here's some example code to help show what I mean:

JSF page:

```xhtml
<ui:repeat var="item" value="#{myBackingBean.listOfItems}">
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <h:outputText value="#{item.name}" />
        <p:commandLink value="(Change name to foo)" action="#{myBackingBean.changeNameToFoo(item)}" />
        <p:commandLink value="(Delete this item)" action="#{myBackingBean.deleteThisItem(item)}" />
    </h:panelGrid>
</ui:repeat>
```

MyBackingBean.java:

```java
public void changeNameToFoo(Item i) {
    i.setName("foo");
}

public void deleteThisItem(Item i) {
    i.remove();
}
```

My situation is this: Say the listOfItems returns a list of five Items with the names [1, 2, 3, 4, 5].  Two different users load up this page at the same time.  User A immediately deletes item 2, and now
sees [1, 3, 4, 5].  User B, who still sees all five items, then tries to change item 3's name to foo.  When his page refreshes, he now sees [1, 3, foo, 5].  Because a user he wasn't even aware of
removed the second item in the list, a completely different item than the one he clicked was changed.

Am I missing something, or is this really a showstopping problem when multiple users enter the picture?

Thanks!

Comment: That sounds like something that your application needs to handle. Since, the list is shared among multiple users, you should design your application accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are allowing multiple users share some resources you have to make sure you handle the situations accordingly. And this applies not only to JSF but for any situations that might have threading issues.
I dont know how big your application is but if it is small enough to not create a problem, then i would synchronize the methods that set and get the information from the listOfItems.

As i said, you might take a performance hit and it depends on whether you are OK with that (and your users of course)